# How to align text with img in ul li HTML

Tags: html, css, html-helper, helper

I want to make a page similar to Instagram to train techniques etc, but I can not align the texts with the photos, follow the code and pictures.

```css
.div-stories {
  width: 100%;
  height: 104px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.stories {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.stories ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pic-stories {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.more-stories {
  position: static;
  top: 63px;
  left: 37px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.txt-stories ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.txt-stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.effect-stories {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: double 6px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #C82D8D, #F99C4B);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-stories">
  <nav class="stories">
    <ul>
      <li><img class="pic-stories" src="img/stories1.jpg"><img class="more-stories" src="img/more-stories.webp"></li>

      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories2.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories3.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories4.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories5.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories6.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories7.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories8.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories9.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

    <nav class="txt-stories">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">Seu story</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">shinigami...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">italo_rmds</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">rodrigotea...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">princejack...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">viainfinda</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">designer.bot</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">mjacksonh</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">reyzeryt</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


  </nav>
</div>
```

I'm learning html and css

Comment: I have no reputation for publishing the photos but it's the same as instagram's stories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you; using **Flexbox** you can align items either in rows or columns pretty easily without defining exact sizes. This also helps keep the names aligned even if they are not the same size.

The `width` I set on the container is just to demonstrate how each item spreads out and aligns with its name; you can set this however you want

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

.stories {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: double 6px white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #C82D8D, #F99C4B);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="stories">
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username large</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username very large</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username</span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="" class="pic">
      <span>username</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro this fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `height: 104px;` from `.div-stories` it will wrap your content inside the gray background.

```css
.div-stories {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.stories {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.stories ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pic-stories {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.more-stories {
  position: static;
  top: 63px;
  left: 37px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.txt-stories ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.txt-stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.effect-stories {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: double 6px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #C82D8D, #F99C4B);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-stories">
  <nav class="stories">
    <ul>
      <li><img class="pic-stories" src="img/stories1.jpg"><img class="more-stories" src="img/more-stories.webp"></li>

      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150g"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></li>
    </ul>

    <nav class="txt-stories">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">Seu story</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">shinigami...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">italo_rmds</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">rodrigotea...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">princejack...</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">viainfinda</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">designer.bot</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">mjacksonh</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">reyzeryt</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/pGEZOp

Comment: I added different images because I do not have access to your files/images

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to change your HTML but if you want keep your HTML, you can add this css rules :

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin-left:5px !important;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:82px;
  text-align:center;
}
ul li p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:hidden;
  font-size:14px;
}
.pic-stories {
  margin:0;
}
```

## Full code :

```css
.div-stories {
  width: 100%;
  height: 104px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.stories {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.stories ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pic-stories {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.more-stories {
  position: static;
  top: 63px;
  left: 37px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.txt-stories ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.txt-stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.effect-stories {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: double 6px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #C82D8D, #F99C4B);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin-left:5px !important;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:82px;
  text-align:center;
}
ul li p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:hidden;
  font-size:14px;
}
.pic-stories {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-stories">
  <nav class="stories">
    <ul>
      <li><img class="pic-stories" src="img/stories1.jpg"><img class="more-stories" src="img/more-stories.webp"></li>

      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories2.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories3.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories4.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories5.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories6.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories7.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories8.jpg"></li>
      <li><img class="pic-stories effect-stories" src="img/stories9.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

    <nav class="txt-stories">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">Seu story</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">shinigami</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">italo_rmds</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">rodrigotea</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">princejack</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">viainfinda</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">designer.bot</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">mjacksonh</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p class="text-stories">reyzeryt</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution have a new HTML and use "data-title" attribut :

## Modern and short fast solution :

[image: example]

```css
div.stories {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

div.stories ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

div.stories ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px !important;
  width: 82px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.stories ul li::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  font-size: 14px;
}

img {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: double 6px white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #C82D8D, #F99C4B);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="stories">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li data-title="username one"><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/57.jpg"></li>
      <li data-title="username two"><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/51.jpg"></li>
      <li data-title="username tree"><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/52.jpg"></li>
      <li data-title="username four"><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/53.jpg"></li>
      <li data-title="username five"><img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/54.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```